# netlify deployment: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2

Tags: reactjs, netlify

I'm trying to deploy my reactjs site to Netlify via Github but it was unsuccessful.

The error message was

> Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero
> exit code: 2

The following is the full Netlify log.

```
11:59:46 AM: Build ready to start
11:59:48 AM: build-image version: b0258b965567defc4a2d7e2f2dec2e00c8f73ad6
11:59:48 AM: build-image tag: v3.4.1
11:59:48 AM: buildbot version: 0a44c930054be748eff0c581d346282fece89cc0
11:59:48 AM: Building without cache
11:59:48 AM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
11:59:48 AM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
11:59:48 AM: git clone https://github.com/Helloiain/movie-app
11:59:49 AM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
11:59:50 AM: Starting build script
11:59:50 AM: Installing dependencies
11:59:50 AM: Python version set to 2.7
11:59:51 AM: v12.18.0 is already installed.
11:59:52 AM: Now using node v12.18.0 (npm v6.14.4)
11:59:52 AM: Started restoring cached build plugins
11:59:52 AM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
11:59:52 AM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.1, read from environment
11:59:53 AM: Using ruby version 2.7.1
11:59:54 AM: Using PHP version 5.6
11:59:54 AM: 5.2 is already installed.
11:59:54 AM: Using Swift version 5.2
11:59:54 AM: Started restoring cached node modules
11:59:54 AM: Finished restoring cached node modules
11:59:54 AM: Started restoring cached yarn cache
11:59:54 AM: Finished restoring cached yarn cache
11:59:54 AM: Installing yarn at version 1.22.4
11:59:54 AM: Installing Yarn!
11:59:54 AM: > Downloading tarball...
11:59:54 AM: [1/2]: https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/1.22.4/yarn-v1.22.4.tar.gz --> /tmp/yarn.tar.gz.aq7yGqZqlV
11:59:54 AM:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
11:59:54 AM:                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
11:59:54 AM:   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
11:59:54 AM: 100    80  100    80    0     0    285      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   285
11:59:54 AM:   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
11:59:54 AM: 100    93  100    93    0     0    156      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   556
11:59:55 AM: 100   643  100   643    0     0    749      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   749
11:59:55 AM: 100 1215k  100 1215k    0     0   947k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  947k
11:59:55 AM: [2/2]: https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/1.22.4/yarn-v1.22.4.tar.gz.asc --> /tmp/yarn.tar.gz.aq7yGqZqlV.asc
11:59:55 AM: 100    84  100    84    0     0   3088      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3088
11:59:55 AM: 100    97  100    97    0     0   1692      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1692
11:59:55 AM: 100   647  100   647    0     0   7321      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  7321
11:59:55 AM:   0  1028    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
11:59:55 AM: 100  1028  100  1028    0     0   8135      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 1003k
11:59:55 AM: > Verifying integrity...
11:59:55 AM: gpg: Signature made Mon 09 Mar 2020 03:52:13 PM UTC using RSA key ID 69475BAA
11:59:55 AM: gpg: Good signature from "Yarn Packaging <yarn@dan.cx>"
11:59:55 AM: gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
11:59:55 AM: gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
11:59:55 AM: Primary key fingerprint: 72EC F46A 56B4 AD39 C907  BBB7 1646 B01B 86E5 0310
11:59:55 AM:      Subkey fingerprint: 6D98 490C 6F1A CDDD 448E  4595 4F77 6793 6947 5BAA
11:59:55 AM: > GPG signature looks good
11:59:55 AM: > Extracting to ~/.yarn...
11:59:55 AM: > Adding to $PATH...
11:59:56 AM: > Successfully installed Yarn 1.22.4! Please open another terminal where the `yarn` command will now be available.
11:59:56 AM: Installing NPM modules using Yarn version 1.22.4
11:59:57 AM: yarn install v1.22.4
11:59:57 AM: [1/4] Resolving packages...
11:59:58 AM: [2/4] Fetching packages...
12:00:22 PM: info fsevents@2.1.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
12:00:22 PM: info "fsevents@2.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
12:00:22 PM: info fsevents@1.2.12: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
12:00:22 PM: info "fsevents@1.2.12" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
12:00:22 PM: [3/4] Linking dependencies...
12:00:22 PM: warning " > @testing-library/user-event@7.2.1" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=5".
12:00:22 PM: warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
12:00:34 PM: [4/4] Building fresh packages...
12:00:36 PM: success Saved lockfile.
12:00:36 PM: Done in 38.98s.
12:00:36 PM: NPM modules installed using Yarn
12:00:36 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
12:00:36 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
12:00:36 PM: go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
12:00:36 PM: go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
12:00:36 PM: Installing missing commands
12:00:36 PM: Verify run directory
12:00:37 PM: ​
12:00:37 PM: ┌─────────────────────────────┐
12:00:37 PM: │        Netlify Build        │
12:00:37 PM: └─────────────────────────────┘
12:00:37 PM: ​
12:00:37 PM: ❯ Version
12:00:37 PM:   @netlify/build 5.0.2
12:00:37 PM: ​
12:00:37 PM: ❯ Flags
12:00:37 PM:   deployId: 5f9069020af24e00933f58d3
12:00:37 PM:   mode: buildbot
12:00:37 PM: ​
12:00:37 PM: ❯ Current directory
12:00:37 PM:   /opt/build/repo
12:00:37 PM: ​
12:00:37 PM: ❯ Config file
12:00:37 PM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
12:00:37 PM: ​
12:00:37 PM: ❯ Context
12:00:37 PM:   production
12:00:37 PM: ​
12:00:37 PM: ┌───────────────────────────────────┐
12:00:37 PM: │ 1. Build command from Netlify app │
12:00:37 PM: └───────────────────────────────────┘
12:00:37 PM: ​
12:00:37 PM: $ yarn build
12:00:38 PM: yarn run v1.22.4
12:00:38 PM: $ react-scripts build
12:00:39 PM: Creating an optimized production build...
12:00:41 PM: Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run the following command: `npx browserslist --update-db`
12:00:42 PM: Failed to compile.
12:00:42 PM: 
12:00:42 PM: ./src/index.js
12:00:42 PM: Cannot find file './app.js' in './src'.
12:00:42 PM: error Command failed with exit code 1.
12:00:42 PM: info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
12:00:42 PM: ​
12:00:42 PM: ┌─────────────────────────────┐
12:00:42 PM: │   "build.command" failed    │
12:00:42 PM: └─────────────────────────────┘
12:00:42 PM: ​
12:00:42 PM:   Error message
12:00:42 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: yarn build
12:00:42 PM: ​
12:00:42 PM:   Error location
12:00:42 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
12:00:42 PM:   yarn build
12:00:42 PM: ​
12:00:42 PM:   Resolved config
12:00:42 PM:   build:
12:00:42 PM:     command: yarn build
12:00:42 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
12:00:42 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/build
12:00:42 PM: Caching artifacts
12:00:42 PM: Started saving node modules
12:00:42 PM: Finished saving node modules
12:00:42 PM: Started saving build plugins
12:00:42 PM: Finished saving build plugins
12:00:42 PM: Started saving yarn cache
12:00:42 PM: Finished saving yarn cache
12:00:42 PM: Started saving pip cache
12:00:42 PM: Finished saving pip cache
12:00:42 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
12:00:42 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
12:00:42 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
12:00:42 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
12:00:42 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
12:00:42 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
12:00:42 PM: Started saving go dependencies
12:00:42 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
12:00:45 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
12:00:45 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
12:00:45 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
12:00:45 PM: Finished processing build request in 57.736891768s
```

Having searched for similar problems I thought it could be dependency issue, however, after using ‘Yarn’ to install dependencies I still get the same problem. And building locally with "yarn build" works fine.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I found the same error when trying to deploy my single-page **React JS** web applications to Netlify.

Following is the procedure I followed to solve the issue and successfully deploy the site.

1. Go to **Site Settings**.

   [image: Site Settings]
2. Select **Build & Deploy** dropdown from the menu.
3. Select **Continuous Deployment** tab from the dropdown.
4. Under the section **Build Settings**, Select **Edit settings**.

   - Change the ***build command*** as
     `CI= npm run build`
   - Click **Save**.

   [image: Build Settings]
5. Then select **Environment** tab from the dropdown.

   - Select **Edit variables**.
   - As the ***Key*** enter `CI` and, as the ***value*** enter `false`.
   - Click **Save**.

   [image: Environment Settings]
6. Finally retrying the deploying the site again.

This will help you to solve the issue related to hosting 'Rect JS' Applications in Netlify & your application will be deployed successfully.

Comment: it works! do all React apps have to be done this way? this isn't even on their Documentation, shouldn't Nelify fix or patch this up?

Comment: I think it is in their documentation @Jae Lee https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/troubleshooting-tips/#build-fails-on-warning-message

Comment: I had this same issue. It was failing because ESLint failed. You can use `CI=true npm run build` to run the same command Netlify runs and see the failures.

Comment: it worked, though only first step required for me i.e changing CI= npm run build

Answer (score 14):

Follow these exact steps, as I was having the same issue until I did this as stated:

1. Go to **Site Settings** > **Build & Deploy** > **Continuous Deployment**.
2. Go to **Build Settings** > **Edit Settings**.
3. Edit your **Build Command** to `CI= npm run build` (Look at the space between `npm run build` and `=`. It is very important to have it).
4. In **Publish Directory** write `build`.
5. Go to **Environment** > **Edit Variables**.
6. You must write in **Key** the variable `CI` and in **Value** write `false`.
7. Click on **Save**.
8. Go to **Deploys** and in the second section, click on **Trigger Deploy** and select Clear Cache and Deploy Site.

This will solve the bug and now you can have your site deployed. Enjoy!

Comment: Changing Publish Directory from the default 'dist' to 'build' fixed it for me, after trying the CI= and environment variable change mentioned by others.

Answer (score 12):

You have to change the environment variable value so that it builds successfully. Follow the steps below:

- Go to `Deploy settings`.
- Click on `Environment` and then click `Edit Variables` button.
- Set **Key** to `CI` and **Value** to `false`.
- Now click on the `Save` button.

Now you can build and deploy your project without getting the error.

Comment: It works!!!
Thank you for your kind explanation. You saved my day.
But I am still not getting how it works.

Comment: @Sergio You can read this doc in your free time. Also, you can Google more about `Environment variables`.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to your project on Netlify, and pick the `Site Settings` page in the `Environment` section to resolve an issue with Netlify.

Save after adding two new Environment variables:

1. CI with the value false
2. NPM_FLAGS with the value `--legacy-peer-deps`

Re-deploy your website again.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the node version in deployment to 16.x fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing during Netlify deployment could be related to the Node.js version being used in the build environment. Specifying the correct Node.js version can resolve such issues.

### How to Specify Node.js Version:

Create a `.nvmrc` file in the root directory of your project.

Add Node.js Version: Given that many modern packages require Node.js v14 or higher, it's a good idea to specify Node.js v14 or v16 in your .nvmrc file:

```
16
```

With the next deploy, you should see the Netlify pick up your node version from the file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. it was the casing of app.js, I just had to change it to App.js,

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same error, but my error cleared using this command
CI= npm run build, but then once again i faced the same error then tried this but this time it doesn't work but i solved the issue by following methods:

- if the deployment failed try to revert the push and try again using
  CI= npm run build
- Most of the errors are due to the new version or unsupported packages you have installed(mismatching with the netlify optimization)
- There will be always a error message that will show in the terminal, try to identify the package which cause error - try to remove or query about the version supported with the netlify

Comment: Releasing of new version for the package is always goes on, this cause more trouble for me to handle netlify so I swifited my deployment platform to aws-amplify;
it is so simple and most errors cause by netlify were not happening here

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I had a compiling error but I didn't know because unstaged local changes were hiding it on my local environment.

In my case `newFile.js` wasn't committed yet. But `newFile.js` was imported into `committedFile.js`. Since `newFile.js` wasn't committed, the build failed to compile with no file available to import into `committedFile.js`.

**Do this to see if you have a hidden compiling error:**

Stash local uncommitted changes with `git stash -u` and see if you get a compiling error locally.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Site Configuration > Build & Deploy > Continuous deployment > Build settings > Edit(Configure).
2. Edit your Build Command to CI= npm run build (Exact word with space).
3. Go to Environment variables   > Add a Variable. Add Key=CI and value=false
4. After All I got same error. so i will change my node version that installed on my local system.
5. Go to Site Configuration > Build & Deploy > Continuous deployment > Dependency management > Edit(Configure) > Node.js version. [16.x] > Save.
6. Again go to Deploys > Trigger deploy > Clear cache and deploy site.